# Delegating my contacts do not show contact groups to other party

Tags: google-workspace, google-contacts, contacts-group

I have Google Apps. I have delegated my Google Contacts to a colleague with full editing rights. He can see and edit contacts and contacts remain in the groups I had assigned them to, but he cannot see the groups at his end.

Is it possible for him to see and edit groups?

Answer (score 1):

No, from the help article on [delegating access to contacts](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2590392?hl=en) "Your assistant will now be able to access all contacts in your My Contacts group." which implies they will not have access to any other contact groups you may have created.